# Define a `Call` node in `astroid`

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, astroid

I would like to define a node such as this one :

```
from astroid import parse
print_node = parse("print()")

print(print_node.body[0].value)

# Call(func=<Name.print l.1 at 0x1abe5f02978>,
#      args=[],
#      keywords=None)
```

The only way I found to define it is:

```
new_print_node = astroid.Call()
new_print_node.postinit(func=print_node.body[0].value.func)
```

Is it possible to get directly the functions by instantiating a `NodeNG` as suggested by the [documentation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/projects/astroid/en/latest/api/astroid.nodes.html?highlight=print#astroid.nodes.Call) ? I have not found how to define the `print` function from [`NodeNG`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/projects/astroid/en/latest/api/base_nodes.html#astroid.node_classes.NodeNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Node` is simply a [`Name`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/projects/astroid/en/latest/api/astroid.nodes.html#astroid.nodes.Name) with name `print`.

Such as `astroid.Name(name="print")`

```
print_node = astroid.Call()
print_node.postinit(
    func=astroid.Name(name="print")
)
```

Which gives :

```
Call(func=<Name.print l.None at 0x249099ac710>,
     args=[],
     keywords=None)
```